# Laravel Login without User Model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I m working on a website in which user login does'nt need User model or database. Laravel call the Post request to API it returns the response message and temprory key. The returned temp_id and key should be used in all subsequent calls. E.g Posting a Checkout Form

if the temp key is set the user considered to be logged in else user will be redirected to login form

how i can check the user with

```
if (Auth::check())
{
// The user is logged in...
}
```

P.S sorry for bad english

Answer (score 2):

For that I would create a new Auth-controller that communicates with the API, check the credentials and finally stores the Session.

That's not quite a problem. A brief explanation can be read here: http://anthon.io/how-to-create-a-custom-auth-driver-in-laravel-4/

Hope that helps